# Unable to run parallel appium tests using selenium grid 4

Tags: appium, selenium-grid

Problem
I have got the below configuration as per appium selenium grid 4+ docs - https://appium.io/docs/en/2.1/guides/grid/. However, I am unable to execute the tests in parallel. I can see one test running on one device but the test on other device gets stuck. Any help would be appreciated here as I have been struggling with it for a long time.

My strategy is
start 2 Appium servers - one of device 1 and other for device 2
start 2 nodes - with 2 device caps
start 1 selenium hub

```
 `# node1.toml

\[server\]
port = 5555

\[node\]
detect-drivers = false

\[relay\]
url = "http://localhost:4723"
status-endpoint = "/status"
configs = \[
"1", "{"platformName": "iOS", "appium:platformVersion": "16.2", "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 1", "appium:automationName": "XCUITest"}"
\]\`
```

```
`# appium1.yml

server:
port: 4723
use-drivers:
\- xcuitest
default-capabilities:
wdaLocalPort: 8100
mjpegServerPort: 9100
mjpegScreenshotUrl: "http://localhost:9100"\`
```

```
<kbd># node2.toml

\[server\]
port = 5565

\[node\]
detect-drivers = false

\[relay\]
url = "http://localhost:4733"
status-endpoint = "/status"
configs = \[
"1", "{"platformName": "iOS", "appium:platformVersion": "16.2", "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 2", "appium:automationName": "XCUITest"}"
\]</kbd>
```

```
<kbd># appium2.yml

server:
port: 4733
use-drivers:
\- xcuitest
default-capabilities:
wdaLocalPort: 8200
mjpegServerPort: 9200
mjpegScreenshotUrl: "http://localhost:9200"</kbd>
```

I start appium and hub node using the below commands where I specify the max-session CLI flag when starting node [not sure whether this is right or wrong

`appium --config appium1.yml  appium --config appium2.yml  java -jar /path/to/selenium.jar node --config node1.toml --max-sessions 4  java -jar /path/to/selenium.jar node --config node2.toml --max-sessions 4  java -jar /path/to/selenium.jar hub 24`

Please do correct if I shouldn't be using max-sessions via CLI

Comment: You cannot have more than 1 active session running a mobile application test on a mobile device at the same time so max-sessions is redundant or should be 1